# VNC and Putty not connecting to raspberry pi 3b+ headless again, internet connection also affected by raspberry pi connection

Tags: vnc, headless, hotspot, putty, raspberry-pi-os-bullseye

I have been using my Raspberry Pi 3b+ model for months now, with the headless setup.
I connected the pi to my laptop hotspot (i.e., added the wpa_supplicant.conf file containing my hotspot ssid and password ,and ssh file to the boot partition) and could use vnc viewer and putty to connect to it.

I recently tried to create a project using hot glue on the pi, and it has been downhill from then on... I do not know if that is the source of the problem.

For 2 days, now, when I turn on my laptop hotspot, my internet connection (on my laptop, itself) becomes very slow. When the pi connects to the hotspot, the entire internet connection doesn't work, putty returns "network error: software caused connection abort", and the vnc loads endlessly until it eventually says the connection was closed remotely.

There have been times when, after trying over and over again, they both worked (during this time, my internet connection was working properly). But only for a short while, as the connection eventually disconnected (and the internet connection stopped again).

NB: I never needed to have a good internet connection when viewing my pi previously. All that was required was for them to be on the same network.

Also, I have tried pinging the pi from my laptop's cmd prompt, and there are no lost packets, meaning they are communicating properly, yes?

Please, help.
I have tried using another computer, and the same thing happened.

Comment: The only surprising thing is that it EVER worked! Normally you can get internet but not ssh etc. You have not listed any details which would help.

Comment: Hey, Milliways. Please what details would help clarify the problem? I'm more of a beginner, so I do not know the technical terms that would work best.

Comment: On the Pi output of `ip a && ip r` network details of whatever laptop you are using and how you set it up